# how to get a data from HtmlElementView in flutter-web

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

i am having a trouble with adding webview in side flutter web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html' as html;

class UserAddress3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserAddress3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserAddress3> createState() => _UserAddress3State();
}

class _UserAddress3State extends State<UserAddress3> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'html.iframeElement',
        (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
          ..src = 'https://daum_postcode_mobile'
          ..style.width = '100%'
          ..style.height = '100%'
          ..style.border = 'none');

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('주소 검색'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: HtmlElementView(
          viewType: 'html.iframeElement',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'https://daum_postcode_mobile' this link leads to where we can  find a address

so the web-view displays fine but i can't have a datas if I click the address

I thought it would work as same as how Webview worked in Flutter App but it seems totaly different...

Is there any one knows how to get datas from HtmleElementView???

p.s and this is my codes which used in my app

```
  class KakaoAddress extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KakaoAddressState createState() => _KakaoAddressState();
}

class _KakaoAddressState extends State<KakaoAddress> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: const Text(
          '주소 검색',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          SampleMenu(),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://daum_postcode_mobile',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          ].toSet(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Daum',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) async {
          final myJsonAsString = message.message;
          dynamic received = json.decode(myJsonAsString);
          dynamic address = received["address"];
          Navigator.pop(context, address);
        });
  }
}

class SampleMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        return IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.close,
              size: 25.0,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar, which may help you. I handled mouse clicks performed inside HtmlElementView, with Dart code, the following way:

In the code passed to ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory() I used  DOM manipulation to attach a listener to the onClick event of an element.

You can do the same with a custom event and trigger that event anytime from Javascript to call and pass data to the Dart side.